# DLL failed to load issue when using requests_gssapi, Python

Tags: python, python-requests, spnego

In my Python script I need gssapi as authentication mechanism when applying requests package.

It came to my attention that package requests_gssapi seems promising for my purpose.

After "pip install requests_gssapi" and import it I got this:

```
>>> from requests_gssapi import HTTPSPNEGOAuth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\opt\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests_gssapi\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .gssapi_ import HTTPSPNEGOAuth, REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, DISABLED  # noqa
  File "C:\opt\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests_gssapi\gssapi_.py", line 6, in <module>
    import gssapi
  File "C:\opt\Python36\lib\site-packages\gssapi\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from gssapi.raw.types import NameType, RequirementFlag, AddressType  # noqa
  File "C:\opt\Python36\lib\site-packages\gssapi\raw\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from gssapi.raw.creds import *  # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

To me it seemed that extra package needs to be installed, but how?

Please help, thanks

Comment: I try to use gssapi module (Windows 10) and have got the same problem.